# "Unexpected operator" error when comparing strings in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to create a shell script that runs a command and plays music if the output of running the other script is nonempty. So far, I have this. However, I keep getting "Unexpected operator" errors on the last line. What is the issue with the code?

As an additional note, I've verified that myscript works fine, and running vlc from the command-line like that works as well.

```
#!/bin/sh

TOF=`myscript | cat`
EMPTYSTR=""

if [ "$TOF" == "$EMPTYSTR" ]; then
    echo "vlc somemusicfile.mp3"
fi
```

Comment: yes. I think the problem was that I used == to compare two strings instead of =.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing for string equality works using `=`. (As a matter of fact, equality is wrong here. You'd want to use *inequality*). However, you could simply use `-n "$TOF"` to check for a non-empty string.

Also, using `|cat` is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, that's it, `bash` works with both `=` and `==` and this is what I missed.

Comment: At least on Debian-based systems, `/bin/sh` is symlinked to `dash`, which will fail the way the OP described when using `==`.

Comment: Yes, @fnl, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

```
test -z "$(myscript)" || echo "vlc somemusicfile.mp3"
```

(though I don't know what's wrong with your code, maybe I'm missing some bashism, you can try changing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: Do you want something for empty or non-empty result? If it is empty, like in your code and not as in your prose, then change `||` to `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
#!/bin/sh

TOF=`myscript | cat`

if [[ -z "$TOF" ]]
then
  echo "vlc somemusicfile.mp3"
fi
```

also you can change your script to `return 0` on success and `return 1` on fail:

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -s somemusicfile.mp3 ]]
then
  return 0
else
  echo "File does not contain music" 
  return 1
fi
```

and check this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

if myscript
then
  echo "vlc somemusicfile.mp3"
fi
```